# Daily review limit exceeded

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits, rate-limiting, review-stats

I have just reached my limit of suggested edits for the day when I noticed someone else has 21, when the limit is 20, how can this be?

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/INoDS.jpg]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If the post on which one of the edits was performed is deleted, it does not count against the total for the day, but still counts as progress in the queue.

Comment: But if the post is deleted, why isn't decrement the counter by one? Seems logical to me to do this..

Comment: @ndsmyter I can't really speak to that decision making process, my guess would be that it's easier to log all of the edits, including the deleted ones, and just keep track of that count in the permanent record.  I would imagine the daily counts are not retained.

Comment: @ndsmyter In some of the queues, one of the review actions you can take is to delete a post. More generally, reviews often help identify poor content *so that it may be deleted*. This would be silly if deleted posts didn't count towards your reviews.

Comment: We had that problem initially, that your review cout was always lower in the morning than it had been the evening before. Didn't exactly encourage the reviewers!

Answer (score 19):

There is another reason.

If someone suggests an edit on one of your own questions or answers, you can still approve or reject the suggested edit, even if you have reached the limit for the day.

I got 21 reviews on suggested edits one time *because* of this behavior.