# How can one break the limit of 20 review a day?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Daily review limit exceeded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158335/daily-review-limit-exceeded)

I just saw that the user *akjoshi* has reviews 21 first posts. How is that possible? I get a no-no after the 20th...

I saw it [right here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/stats).

Comment: (briefly, deleted posts count towards the number you have reviewed, but not against your daily total, and any edits you've approved on your own posts count towards reviews)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far I know it is possible to increase this limit by editing a question instead of just approving/rejecting.

See also [How do the review limits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147973/171881)

Comment: Strange still. I edit questions very often but never got above 20. May one needs to edit the 20th and this **might** has never happened to me before.

Comment: My personal *record* was about 50, but this has may changed. That time there were just 3 votes nessesary and there was no tests if your voting makes sense.