# Exceeding daily review limit

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits, low-quality-posts

First of all, let me tell you, I have gone through [**this question**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158335/daily-review-limit-exceeded) which gave me the right answer about exceeding daily review limit of "Suggested Edit". But, in the same day I saw someone has exceeded the daily limit of "Low Quality Posts". As you can see, it is exceeded by 7.

[image]

Exceeding limit of "Suggested Edits" happened to me when I reached the daily limit before someone suggested an edit on my post and I approved it. As the question in the link says:

> If someone suggests an edit on one of your own questions or answers, you can still approve or reject the suggested edit, even if you have reached the limit for the day. And it still counts as progress in the queue.

My question is : How this could happen in "Low Quality Posts". As you can see a moderator had reviewed 27 low quality posts on the same day. I guess everyone in SO (including moderators) has the same daily limit for reviewing.

Comment: That's a moderator, you didn't obfuscate the diamond. Moderators are not limited by the same rules as us mere mortals.

Comment: Now it makes sense. I am glad @BilltheLizard is more concerned about the quality of SO. ;-)