# Not getting extra review slot after post is deleted

Tags: bug, review

Today, I did 20 reviews in the Suggested Edits queue on Stack Overflow. However, one of the edit suggestions was to a post that was removed shortly after.

I'd expected that the used slot would come free; it's happened before and is how this is supposed to work. Looking at the [SE Review Queue stats](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/stats), another reviewer did get 21 reviews today, so it seems this rule hasn't changed.

So I'm wondering - where's my extra slot?

**Edit**
The user with 21 reviews also reviewed an edit to their own post, which is an exception to the 20-reviews rule.

Comment: It might take a while before the script that determines that runs? Or maybe the deletion should have happened before you finished all 20 reviews?

Comment: @rene The deletion did happen before I did all the reviews. Does that make a difference then?

Comment: I know the effect, but I'm trying to find a post that confirms if it is a bug or a feature. In the former case you could say that the behavior is undefined.

Comment: OK, it is a [feature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158335/daily-review-limit-exceeded). So how long ago did you finish reviewing?

Comment: @rene 2 hours ago, according to the history. http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8851457 . I wonder if the fact that the last one was an audit plays into this.

Comment: @rene Maybe I'm missing something, but the question you linked doesn't seem to differentiate between posts deleted during or after all slots are used.

Comment: That is correct, I didn't recall the correct conditions needed. And if you finished 2 hours ago I would think you should have gotten it back by now. Assuming that give-review-task-back job is in the 15 minutes or hour script.

Comment: I'm not sure the linked post is correct; it gives no citations, and an alternate explanation -- that it's a simple race condition or the result of reviewing one's own post edits -- wasn't properly rejected.

Comment: The same thing happened today, only now the post was deleted after I'd done 20 edit reviews. It seems the rule has changed, and we don't get our review slots back anymore?